# Removing Picture insertions for Chapters from Template

Tags: errors, chapters, templates

I'm got this template that gives me errors like this one:

```
LaTeX Error: File `' not found.
 
‪main.tex, 74‬
The compiler cannot find the file you want to include. Make sure that you have uploaded the file and specified the file location correctly.
```

For every `\chapter` and for my Table of Contents `\tableofcontents`.
I think the template wants to insert a picture at every chapter, however I don't want any pictures here.
I think I found the part where this is implemented, but since I'm fairly new to LaTeX I don't know how to remove the Image insertion or how to avoid the Errors.

How do I get rid of the Errors without using Pictures?

Link to structure.tex: https://github.com/PIX3LFLUX/HSK-Latex-Skript-Template/blob/main/structure.tex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template mentions a switch called `usechapterimage` which can be set to true or false. If it is set to true then you must also use the command `\chapterimage` to provide the filename of the chapter image. If the switch is true but the filename is not provided then the error that is mentioned in the question occurs.

The following code (copied from `00_main.tex`) switches the chapter image off and comments the filename setting:

```
\usechapterimagefalse % If you don't want to include a chapter image, use this to toggle images off - it can be enabled later with \usechapterimagetrue

%\chapterimage{Pictures/csm_HKA_FK-EIT_2017-9363_a9e6e1d039.jpg} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers for the following pages

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right side of the book

\pagestyle{fancy} % Enable headers and footers again


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Teil 1
\part{TEIL 1}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{01_einleitung.tex}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that you didn't provide the code of your own document in the question, so it is difficult to say where exactly you should put the relevant code (i.e., the first line, consisting of `\usechapterimagefalse`). However, it should be somewhere before the first time you use `\chapter` but after you load `structure.tex` (because there the switch is turned to true).

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it